# wp_localize_script() and JavaScript namespaces

Tags: php, javascript, wp-localize-script, namespace

As you are aware, [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) allows the creation of a JavaScript object from a PHP object.

So, after running the code in the example below:

```
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'var_name', $var);  // This works
```

We will end with a JavaScript variable named `var_name` that is accessible in the script `my-script`. This JavaScript variable is copied from the original PHP variable `$var`.

Everything is OK so far. The issue I am facing is this: I like to be able to assign `var_name` to a *JavaScript namespace*; so in the following example, inside the object `namespace_name`

```
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'namespace_name.var_name', $var); // This does not work
```

But I am unable to do that, and `wp_localize_script()` throws the following error in the web console: `SyntaxError: unexpected token: '.'`

Is there a way that I enable the use of `wp_localize_script()` with JavaScript namespaces?

**Note:** I am passing a name space, as I like to keep all my JavaScript data within one object, to prevent naming conflicts and reduce clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `wp_localize_script()` is supposed to be used is for that 2nd argument to be your namespace. Then you put an array as the 3rd argument for the values:

```
wp_localize_script(
    'my-script', 
    'namespace_name',
    array(
        'var_name' => $var,
    )
);
```

Now you can access the variable in the script with `namespace_name.var_name`.

If you also use the namespace in your script, instead of initialising the object, retrieve the object created by WordPress (or fall back to a new object if it's missing) and add to it:

```
var namespace_name = window.namespace_name || {};
namespace_name.new_var = 'Hello world!';
```